# Error when inserting NSDate to CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdate

```
    NSDateFormatter *dt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dt setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSDate *bdate = [dt dateFromString:@"02-02-2013"];
    [nouContacte setValue:bdate forKey:@"birthday"];
```

I don't understand why that code doesn't work. It inserts 9 different digits like 318366000.
I can insert strings, "booleans", numbers, but i can't with date.

birthday field in coredata is date type.

any idea?

Answer (score 4):

For a "Date" attribute, Core Data stores the "number of seconds since 1 January 2001, GMT" in the SQLite file, i.e. what you get with

```
[bdate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]
```

For example, `2011-02-02 19:00:00 +0000` is stored as the number `318366000`.

But that is an implementation detail and you should not worry about it.
When reading objects from the SQLite file, the number is converted back do an `NSDate`.